# HTTP authentication cpanel

Tags: javascript, php, cpanel

I want this browser prompt authentication for my cpanel server. I have uploaded my web application to the server now I want to implement browser pop up authentication like in picture below. I know there are many examples but I coudn't crack initial points. I have Html javascript web app on server. I want the prompt user on url hit.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use 'Password Protect Directories' feature of cPanel to accomplish this. Just click on 'Password Protect Directories' option from cPanel and select appropriate directory you want to secure and provide the required details like user name and password

Comment: I have shared hosted cPanel. I couldn't find Password Preotect Directories in my Dashboard

Comment: It could be disabled by hosting provider, you can ask them to enable it. Even, you can ask them to take care of this task for you. If that is not an option for you, you will have to do it manually using .htaccess and .htpassws files. Following URL will help you: 

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

Comment: @AndroConsis I could setup a password protected directory under the menu called `Directory Privacy`.